# (Bootstrap) popover makes button to move?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

http://seedgo0504.esy.es/  <- it's my site url

When i was clicked '*로그인' button,  it adhered to '*가입하기' button.

Can i make the button not move, when i click the button?

*('로그인' means login)
*('가입하기' means become a member)

**index.php**

```
<div class = 'collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class ="nav navbar-nav"> ... </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn" id="login" 
                   data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">로그인</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn ">가입하기</button>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
$("#login").popover({
        html : false,
        content: "가입하기"
});
```

Comment: i don't see a reason for the downvote, the issue was perfectly reproducable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid jumping `button`s, specify a proper `container` for the tooltips:

```js
$("#login").popover({
    html : false,
    content: "가입하기",
    container: 'body'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn" id="login" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">로그인</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn ">가입하기</button>
</ul>
```